# Mid 2014 Macbook Pro Retina 15" monitor daisychain

Tags: macos, display, thunderbolt, displayport, daisy-chaining

I recently bought 2 Dell U2715H monitors to use in a daisy chain configuration to save on thunderbolt port usage. Everything I read said it would work with my Macbook, but so far I have not had any success.

My specs are: 2.5 GHz i7, 16GB DDR3 memory, NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M 2048 MB for graphics.

The first monitor is connected to my laptop via mini-dp to display port in of the first monitor. The second monitor is connected from display port out on the first monitor into the mini-dp in port.

I have enabled DP 1.2 on the first monitor, but I'm not sure if it should be on for the second. I did try it in both configurations but neither worked.

Based on the support pages I've read, my Macbook has DP1.2 support via Thunderbolt 2 and MST was allowed in update 10.10.3 (I'm on 10.10.5). My graphics card can handle this setup based on my research. Am I missing anything obvious?

All I get is a blank screen on both monitors.

Should I try updating to El Capitan?

Answer (score -1):

```
MBP.MiniDisplayOut > Monitor1.DisplayPortIn > Monitor1.DisplayPortOut > Monitor2.DisplayPortIn

NOT:  -> Monitor2.MiniDisplayPortIn
```

Manual [HERE](http://content.etilize.com/User-Manual/1029397078.pdf), page 25